# Inheritance Base class with one instance

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, inheritance, singleton

I want to know if it's possible having something like this:

- basic class A1
- derived class A2 : A1
- derived class A3 : A1

to have only one instance of A1? Because when I use `ctor(params):base(params)` for each derived class `A2`, `A3` create a new instance of `A1` and I want to avoid this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Via inheritance, no. This isn't possible. If you chose composition though, this can be accomplished.

`A1` becomes a Singleton.

`A2` and `A3` both have a reference to the Singleton instance of `A1` and proxies the appropriate calls through to that instance.